# Load Balancer in Azure takes into account type of endpoint?

Tags: azure, load-balancing

In my service i have.
1. A Worker Role.
2.A Web Role
with input endpoints defined for both.
a normal HTTP endpoint for the WebRole and a TCP endpoint on port 80 for the WorkerRole.
My question is that wether the azure loadbalaner will balance the traffic on these two endpoints.treating them as one?
 what i mean by this is suppose i have 2 instances to the WebRole and 2 instances of WorkerRole then i have total 4 input endpoints.
so the LoadBalancer will load balance on 2+2 endpoints or 4 endpoints(treating all four as equal).
if not then what mechanism can be used to reach any one of the two endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspected that the input endpoint you opened on the web role should not be 80, since it had been used by your worker role. So let's say you have an input HTTP endpoint on web role which is 8080, and an input TCP endpoint on worker role that is 80.

And if you have 2 instances for each role, in the load balance there's still two endpoint opened, but you have 4 internal ports on your 4 instances. And the azure load balance will route the request from these 2 public input endpoints to the 4 internal endpoints.

HTH.

Comment: yes thats correct the tcp endpoint is diff. so lets just say itz 8080. so your answer means that the traffic that comes on the endpoint that is opened by webrole(port 80) will get load balanced to two internal endpoints that are on external port 80? and same is true for the other endpoint

Comment: If the web role opens 8080 and has 2 instances, all traffic to the 8080 will go to these to instances' internal port. Same in the worker role. It will not happen that request to 8080 was routed to the worker role's internal port.